# Exec not outputting result to function

Tags: bash, shell

How do I get the result of the find to be used by the function? I keep getting blank results.

```
#!/bin/bash

#functions
function codec_scan () {

 echo "paremter 1 is this: $1" # >> $fulllog

}

#exporting
export -f codec_scan

#Main Code
find . -type f \( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.AVI" -o -name "*.m4v" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.MP4" \) -exec bash -c codec_scan \"\{}\" \;
```

Comment: so if you type `bash -c func arg`, does `func` get's the arg?

Comment: ```bash -c codec_scan arg``` gets ```paremter 1 is this:```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\"\{}\"` is *literal* characters `"` with `{}` inside. It's a sole `{}`. Nothing before it, nothing after it. Unless you want to add a *literal* `"` characters.

It's `bash -c 'script...'`. The arguments that follow are arguments *to the script*, not to the function. Each function has its own `$1 $2 ...` positional arguments, they are separate to script.  And they arguments to `bash -c` start from `$0`, not from `$1`, see `man bash`, it is like `bash -c 'script..' <$0> <$1> <$2> ...`

You want:

```
find ....  -exec bash -c 'codec_scan "$@"' _ {} \;
```

Do not use `function` in bash. Just `codec_scan() {`. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

You may be interested in `-iname`.

Comment: The $1 I thought I read was the first variable and the $0 was the function itself. I must have read wrong. $0 solved it. I dropped the \" 's and the result is as needed. Thank you